# I get an error when trying to login with myOpenID

Tags: support, login, myopenid

I cannot log in with myOpenID. After I click on the "log in with myOpenID" image, I get the following error:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>   No OpenID endpoint found.

It was working a few hours ago. Is this a myOpenID issue or Stack Exchange issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get an error just going to their homepage, so it's probably their fault:

[image: Screenshot of MyOpenID's error page]

Plus, it's pretty much [always their fault](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=myopenid)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the wealth of myopenid related complaints on SO meta :D

Comment: When people register with a myOpenID SO should take them straight to the page that lets you add a backup OpenID, with the message "Trust us...you want to do this"

Comment: @michael see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/ the unreliability of myOpenId was a big reason for that. JanRain doesn't seem to give a f**k any more, and since MyOpenID doesn't contribute to their bottom line I guess that's .. understandable. Still *extremely* bad sportsmanship IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I agree there's something rotten in the state of <s>Denmark</s> MyOpenId -- but **all your accounts are attached to google**.

Why would you need to log in with MyOpenId?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what you mean...I created my openid separately, by using a non-google email. Is there some other mechanism I'm unaware of?

Comment: if you have multiple accounts, email the address provided at the bottom of every page and we can merge them.

Comment: Ah, ok! Seeing all the issues with myopenid, I now think it might be better to switch to my google login. I'll ask to have this account and my normal one merged. Thanks a lot for the heads-up!